# react-fontawesome not displaying icons

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm attempting to using react-fontawesome and implementing it in what seems to me to be exactly the same as the readme: https://github.com/danawoodman/react-fontawesome/blob/master/readme.md

```
import React from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome'
...
export default class ComponentName extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <FontAwesome
                            className='super-crazy-colors'
                            name='rocket'
                            size='2x'
                            spin
                            style={{ textShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }}
                        />
                        SOME TEXT
                    </span>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But I'm not seeing an icon in the DOM. Although I do see in the Chrome Dev Tools:

```
<span style="text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-rocket fa-2x fa-spin super-crazy-colors" data-reactid=".0.$/=11.0.0.$/=10.$/=10.$/=10"></span>
```

which I feel like should be a `<i>` tag. I tried changing the `<span>...</span>` to an `<i>...</i>` in "edit as HTML" in the dev tools and the icon still didn't show.

I have add-module-exports in my plugins and stage-2 in my presets in my webpack.config.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something? Do I need some other package other than react-fontawesome to make this work? Do I need to import the standard font-awesome.css or load a font-awesome CDN? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you really need react font-awesome or just include font-awesome in index.html and use it normally.

Comment: Basically the icon is there or else there wouldn't be any span there. I tried your code, it works perfectly fine on mine. Try changing css color property.

Comment: duwalanise, unfortunately in this case I need it all contained in the React component, ie I can't load the font-awesome.min.css in HTML file.

Comment: DroidNoob, the icon is not there. The span tag could be there with out the icon showing, for instance if the associated CSS weren't loaded: a span tag with `class=fa fa-rocket` wouldn't show the icon.

I tried changing the CSS color property at it didn't do anything.

Comment: @Casey check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44681641/5519872

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem. Read their [Readme.md](https://github.com/danawoodman/react-fontawesome/blob/master/readme.md), and you see that there is this note:

> *Note: This component does not include any of the Font Awesome CSS or fonts, so you'll need to make sure to include those on your end somehow, either by adding them to your build process or linking to [CDN versions](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/).*

So the most simple way is to link to the fontawesome cdn in your html.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">    
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: This solved my problem!! thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: For those of you who don't want to (or can't) use a CDN version, Font Awesome allows you to download the files and host yourself:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

This was helpful for me because I have an app that does not have access to outside networks for security purposes.

Comment: does beside adding this CDN you also need to add your kit? Should it be before or after this CDN link href?

Comment: What's the point of these packages besides overcomplicating life? What's wrong with `<i className="fas fa-eye">`? The doc says to install 3 packages (!) and it still doesn't work out of the box, that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 29):

Run `npm install font-awesome --save`

In your `index.js` or `App.js` or `YourComponent.js`, import the minified CSS file.

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Comment: I get an empty white rectangle after this.

Comment: Isn't that the older version?

Comment: No such file...

Answer (score 26):

As the other answers mention, you need to include the icons in your page somehow. Check out the `react-fontawesome` example here:
https://github.com/danawoodman/react-fontawesome/blob/master/examples/index.html

You can see that the developer has included the font-awesome CSS on line #5.

On a separate note, Font Awesome v5 has been released, and you should consider moving to it. Read relevant docs here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome

To use v5:

Install dependencies:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

Your component can then use icons like so:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'

const element = (
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
)

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body);
```

You can also build a library of commonly used icons in your app, for easy reference. Check out working code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8y251kv448

More details about the library function available here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome#build-a-library-to-reference-icons-throughout-your-app-more-conveniently

Comment: thanks, in react this is the only solution that worked for me so far

Comment: This only works sometimes for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Works with the latest version of Font Awesome after following instructions (v6).

Answer (score 14):

Font Awesome now has an official React component that’s available to use their icons in your React applications.

**Step 1 :**
you must install 3 important packages in your project using a package manager like npm:

```
    npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
    npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
    npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

**Step 2 :**
if you're planning on styling the icons you must download these two extra packages :

```
     npm install --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
     npm install --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
```

**Step 3:**
Once you’ve installed all the packages you need for your project, now you can use the icons.
Import this packages in your component like this:

```
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

After that you can import an icon into your component like this (example
using an icon with the class as "fas fa-atom")

```
   import { faAtom } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

P.S : you can import multiple icons in one import with adding a coma between
each one.

**Step 4 :**
use the imported icons

```
const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAtom} />
```

SOURCE : https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: This answer works. Also, this answer is from fontawesome's official documentation.

Comment: The official docs mention that a string literal can be used to specify the icon. That didn't work for me, it rendered nothing. The solution posted here with the explicit import works, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

The only example I got working that actually seems up-to-date and didn't throw "can't resolve 'react' errors:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-font-awesome-5-with-react

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// get our fontawesome imports
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

// create our App
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
  </div>
);

// render to #root
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: So there's only one problem with this that I am having an issue with, I cannot view the icons before using them. So I have to scroll through them. How do I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work perfectly for React

**Installation:**

```
$ yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

**Usage:**

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body)
```

[Font Awesome 5 React](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#installation)

Answer (score 4):

**NEXT JS** - Import styles this way if you are using NEXT jS

```
import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Alee pointed out Fontaweome fonts aren't included in the package. You will have to import it yourself.

1. Install npm `font-awesome` package. If you use npm run `npm install font-awesome --save` or if you use yarn then run `yarn add font-awesome`
2. Now you just have to import `font-awesome.less` under `less` directory by writing `import 'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less'`

Now you should see your icons working :)

Answer (score 2):

import fontawesome styles from the package itself without loading any external css:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"; // import Font Awesome CSS
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false; // Tell Font Awesome to skip adding the CSS automatically since it's being imported above
```

See [article](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-use-font-awesome-5-icons-in-next-js/) to get more info

Answer (score 2):

copy and paste in your html ...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers don't score as well as those that explain how the code answers the question. When answering an old question with existing answers, it helps to explain how your answer is different from or improves on the others.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have not yet imported the CSS that FontAwesome needs - download the minified CSS file from FontAwesome's Web site and import it into your app.scss file or wherever else you're importing other stylesheets.

The react-fontawesome library is helping you create elements with class names like 'up-arrow', but without the stylesheet, your project will not know that there are icons corresponding to those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Better to install everything all at once and then only import the icon you want,

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core  @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome  @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons  @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSpinner } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

make sure to import the icon from the exact pack, you can use `ctrl` + `space` to use the power of suggections to fiding icons and for changing pack when your importing icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works with FontAwesome 6+ in React, that makes it easy to combine icon packs such as the free and pro ones:

1. Add the FontAwesome dependencies to your project:

   ```bash
   npm install --save \
     @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core \
     @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons \
     @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons \
     @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons \
     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
   ```
2. Declare all FA icons you would like to use in the root of your app:

   ```js
   import { library as fontAwesomeLibrary } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
   import {
     faPlugCircleMinus,
     faPlugCirclePlus,
     faSchool,
     faUsers,
   } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

   fontAwesomeLibrary.add(
     faPlugCircleMinus,
     faPlugCirclePlus,
     faSchool,
     faUsers,
   );
   ```
3. Use a shorthand syntax to display the icons in the relevant components, such as:

   ```js
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
   ...
   const element = (
     <FontAwesomeIcon icon='school' />
   );
   ```

Alternatively, as mentioned by other answers here, you could also import the individual icons whenever needed. The downside of this approach is that you would have to remember which pack each icon comes from every time you add one to a component:

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSchool } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
...
const element = (
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSchool} />
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
<script src='https://use.fontawesome.com/3bd7769ce1.js'></script>
```

to your main index.html within your react project.

Comment: That won't do any good, that's not the React-version of fontawesome