# How to import font-awesome in node.js to use in react.js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, font-awesome

I am working with node.js and react.js.
I already imported my own css file like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import './../App.css';
```

this works fine, but when I try to add font-awesome like so:

```
import './src/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'
```

then it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there maybe another way?

Comment: `then it doesn't work.` - That error is very common and means something very specific is wrong but it won't tell us exactly what. - Is there any errors showing up anywhere? Is the specified location correct and reachable by your code?

Comment: font-awesome import font's with a relative path, importing css by this way break the relative path. Do you use webpack ?

Comment: You are trying to import a css file in javascript? That's not possible. The `import` statement is to *"import functions, objects or primitives that have been exported from an external module, another script, etc."* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: Try out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fa for FontAwesome in React, gives it a nice clean interface.

Comment: Also check out [`react-icons`](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons)

Comment: it worked... all I had to do was replace the `src` with `..`
like this: `import './../font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'`

Comment: it's strange, but it worked out in the end :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how i did it entirely in the front end react side:

1. Include font awesome inside the `<head>` tag

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   ```
2. Install [react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome)

   `npm install --save react-fontawesome`
3. Import the file and use it in your react components

   ```
   import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

   // ..rest of your code
   <FontAwesome name="linkedin" size="2x"/>
   ```